# Allow function to take vectors not just individual values

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to code a program that will allow conversion between polar and cartesian/rectangular coordinates. The code works for individual r and theta values but I want to be able to be able to input vectors containing more than one value (and of the same length as each other) for r and theta. Any help appreciated.

```
import numpy as np

r=float(input('Enter a value for r:'))
theta=float(input('Enter a theta value in radians:'))

def polar2cart(r,theta):
    x=r*(np.cos(theta))
    y=r*(np.sin(theta))
    return x,y
x,y= polar2cart(r,theta)
```

Comment: Why is your function not working on vector inputs? What error do you get?

Comment: `polar2cart(np.arange(5), np.arange(0,0.5,5))` works fine for me. Do you want to be able take multiple input from the `input()` function?

Comment: …and, if so, learn about `numpy.fromstring`

Comment: first you have to get values as list or array but you use `input()` to get only one value.